Cloudflare меняет метод запроса с GET на POST после JS Challenge
В заголовке собственно весь вопрос.
В Cloudflare настроено правило, по которому некоторые пользователи попадают на JS Challenge, но после его прохождения GET запрос (т.е. обычный переход на страницу) по какой-то причине меняется на POST и пользователь получает ошибку потому что этот роут обслуживает только GET запросы. Со стороны самого сервера и nginx никаких редиректов не настроено вообще. Если отключить WAF правило в Cloudflare, то проблема уходит. Но правило нам нужно 100%.
Находил подобную проблему на форме Cloudflare за 2021 год, но ответа там нет. Может кто-то сталкивался?
